# How to implement GeometryReader to (Z/H/V)Stacks in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Unable to implement GeometryReader for ZStack().
Here is an example of implementation of GeometryReader to Text():

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
    return Text("test")
}
```

But when I try to do the same thing with ZStack (or Rectangle, or HStack), I see this:

```swift
GeometryReader {pr -> HStack<Rectangle> in
    return HStack() {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Check this error message, please: https://ibb.co/BBxScg8

Answer (score 1):

GeometryReader gives you a variable to use inside the HStack / VStack, etc.

```
GeometryReader { geo in
   HStack() {
       Rectangle()
          .foregroundColor(Color.red)
          .onTapGesture {
              print("width : \(geo.size.width), height : \(geo.size.height)")
           }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason that's not working is that you're declaring the return type of that closure as `HStack<Rectangle>`, but once you add the foreground color what you are returning is something like `HStack<Rectangle<ForegroundColor>>`.

Just let the compiler infer the return type; get rid of the `-> HStack<Rectangle>` part and it will work.

And also remove the `return` keywords, you don't need them in this context.